# Yeast amounts unsure

Tags: yeast

My recipe calls for .25 ounce package of active dry yeast, and the package of active dry yeast that I purchased from the store is 1/4 ounce packages is this the same amount of active dry yeast that I need for the recipe ??

Comment: ... You mean you're asking if .25 ounce = 1/4 ounce?

Answer (score 1):

1 divided by 4 is 0.25, so yes. 4 times 0.25 is also 1, so yes again.

Comment: This answer is confusing. I don't feel like it sufficiently answers the question. Sure 1 divided by 4 is 0.25 but the OP is asking about 1/4 ounce. And what about 4 times 1/4 ounce? You dance around the answer but don't really nail it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, .25 ounces is the same as 1/4. It's entirely understandable how the numbers can be confusing! Just think about money--a quarter is 1/4 of a whole dollar.